# bash script testing conditionals on multiple paramters on a string

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am working on a bash shell script that tests a string and returns true for the following:

1) Has a minimum of 8 characters

2) Has at least one letter and one number

3) Has both a lowercase and uppercase letter

Through searching I did find how to get the number of characters in a string

```
srtLen=$(echo -m $str | wc -m)
```

And the if statement would be

```
if [ $strLen -ge 8 ]; then
  #make bool var true
fi
```

But I cannot find how to test and return a boolean for if a string has a lower case letter, an uppercase letter and at least one number.  I don't care if each test is separate and I imagine they would be in separate if statements which is why I have mentioned in the code above a boolean variable that will be set based on the conditions.

Comment: `str="foo"; echo "${#str}"`

Comment: Is "one letter" in the English alphabet, or what?

Comment: It can be any letter English alphabet or other alphabet.  For the most part for simplicity sake maybe the English alphabet.

Comment: Any other alphabet requires Unicode which bash does not support.

Comment: So just the English alphabet then.  I am extremely new to linux/bash.  I heard that you could use \w instead of [A-Za-z] so that you can include foreign characters.  Realistically whatever is easier for me to implement to start out.

Comment: `\w` is used in Extended Regular Expressions and is not *exactly* what you want since it includes an `_`: `\w` == `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.  My solution uses glob constructs.

Comment: This reeks of a password policy check. If so, the person providing requirements should read Peter Gutmann's *[Engineering Security](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf)* before you go further. He dedicates an entire chapter to passwords and debunking stupid practices like masks and requiring a letter, number and symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generic answer that will work with non-English locale and multi-byte UTF-8 characters.

Let us translate each of your requirements into `bash` code:

1. `$str` as a minimum of 8 characters: this can be done in several simple ways using bash builtins

   - `[ "${#str}" -ge 8 ] && echo "str has a minimum of 8 characters"`

     Straightforward: we compare the length of `$str`
   - `[[ "$str" == ????????* ]] && echo "str has a minimum of 8 characters"`

     `$str` is checked against a pattern that matches at least 8 characters
   - `[[ "$str" =~ .{8} ]] && echo "str has a minimum of 8 characters"`

     `$str` is checked against a regular expression that matches an 8 character string
   - `[ -n "${str#???????}" ] && echo "str has a minimum of 8 characters"`

     We check that `$str` is not empty when the first 7 characters are removed (not obvious, should be avoided)
2. Has at least one digit:

   - `[[ "$str" == *[[:digit:]]* ]] && echo "str has at least one digit"`

     `$str` is checked against a pattern that matches a digit surrounded by any number of characters
   - `[[ "$str" =~ [[:digit:]] ]] && echo "str has at least one digit"`

     `$str` is checked against a regular expression that matches a single digit
   - `[ -n "${str//[^[:digit:]]}" ] && echo "str has at least one digit"`

     We check that `$str` is not empty when all non-digit characters are removed (not obvious, should be avoided)
3. Has at least one lowercase letter:

   Same as for the digit, just replace `[[:digit:]]` with `[[:lower:]]`

   ```
   [[ "$str" == *[[:lower:]]* ]] && echo "str has at least one lowercase letter"
   [[ "$str" =~ [[:lower:]] ]] && echo "str has at least one lowercase letter"
   [ -n "${str//[^[:lower:]]}" ] && echo "str has at least one lowercase letter"
   ```
4. Has at least one uppercase letter:

   Same as for the digit, just replace `[[:digit:]]` with `[[:upper:]]`

   ```
   [[ "$str" == *[[:upper:]]* ]] && echo "str has at least one uppercase letter"
   [[ "$str" =~ [[:upper:]] ]] && echo "str has at least one uppercase letter"
   [ -n "${str//[^[:upper:]]}" ] && echo "str has at least one uppercase letter"
   ```

You can of course combine the four conditions:

```
$ str='my ßtrÎñ9'
$ if [[ "${#str}" -ge 8 \
    && "$str" =~ [[:digit:]] \
    && "$str" =~ [[:lower:]] \
    && "$str" =~ [[:upper:]] \
  ]]; then
      echo "str is a valid password"
  else
      echo "str is NOT a valid password"
  fi

str is a valid password
```

Answer (score 1):

This is for the English alphabet, if you need others then you need to mess with the locale and the variable `LC_COLLATE`:

```
check_str()
{   
    str="$1"

    # Has a minimum of 8 characters
    if (( ${#str} > 7 )) &&

       # Has at least one number
       [[ "$str" = *[0-9]* ]] &&

       # Has both a lowercase 
       [[ "$str" = *[a-z]* ]] &&
       # and uppercase letter
       [[ "$str" = *[A-Z]* ]]
    then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

while :
do
    read -p "Enter a string: " inp
    if check_str "$inp"
    then
        echo "$str matches"
    else
        echo "$str does not match"
    fi
done
```

Test run:

```
Enter a string: helloHHx
helloHHx does not match
Enter a string: helloH1x
helloH1x matches
Enter a string: 12345678
12345678 does not match
Enter a string: hello
hello does not match
Enter a string: now is The 4 time for all good men
now is The 4 time for all good men matches
```

Note that your criteria 2 and 3 overlap, for 2 we only need check if there is a number, presence of a letter is checked in 3.